# How to link debug executable with release library using CMake FetchContent?

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to link my Debug executable with external library built in Release version using FetchContent.
I'm able to link my Debug executable with Debug built library and similar with Release and Release using:

```
project(CMakeDemo)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET OFF)
FetchContent_Declare(
      ZLIB
      URL  https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
    )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ZLIB)
    
add_executable(CMakeDemo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CMakeDemo ZLIB)
```

So when I execute from a build directory on Windows:

```
cmake ../
cmake --build .
```

Then zlib and my executable is built in Debug version and my executable is linked with that zlib Debug version.

But how to enhance the CMake to build my executable in Debug version but zlib in Release version and link my Debug executable with the zlib Release version? **How to achieve that using FetchContent_Declare**?

(I believe this has to be some common approach because for example when someone wants to use Google Test framework or zlib in a project then for sure he wants to use these external libraries in Release version always)

Comment: If this is with Visual Studio you should not mix debug and release. Debug has its own heap and is incompatible with release. There are also differences in the implementation of the standard library between debug and release.

Comment: `cmake --build . --config Release` maybe a start if you are not using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

`FetchContent()` will integrate the dependency, here ZLIB, in your worktree like an `add_subdirectory()` so flags will be identical (if ZLIB is correctly configured to be use as subproject, spoiler: this is not the case you'll need to patch it...).

If you **really** want to build it in Release, you should try to use `ExternalProject()` and `execute_process()`
to build and install it at configure time then you can use `find_package()` to retrieve this pre-installed dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is old, but as I have been struggling a whole day with the same issue, and wanted to share my progress. Please bear in mind I'm a cmake newbie, and I'm not sure if what I'm doing conforms to best practices, and the example code I provide might have mistakes. It can also definitely be significantly improved - but I believe is sufficient to get someone off the ground, if they're having the same issue.

For my use case, I wanted the external libraries to be built at cmake configure time, instead of build time. To that effect, I used `execute_process` to configure and build the external libraries. This is the function I created for that effect:

```
function(fetch_and_build_lib)
   set(options "")
   set(oneValueArgs LIB_NAME GIT_REPOSITORY GIT_TAG PACKAGE_NAME)
   set(multiValueArgs CONFIG_ARGS CONFIG_TYPES BUILD_ARGS COMPONENTS)
   cmake_parse_arguments(ARG "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN})

   if (NOT DEFINED ARG_LIB_NAME)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "fetch_and_build_lib called without LIB_NAME")
   endif()

   if (NOT DEFINED ARG_GIT_REPOSITORY)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "fetch_and_build_lib called without GIT_REPOSITORY")
   endif()

   if (NOT DEFINED ARG_GIT_TAG)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "fetch_and_build_lib called without GIT_TAG")
   endif()

   if (DEFINED ARG_PACKAGE_NAME)
      set(PACKAGE_NAME ${ARG_PACKAGE_NAME})
   else()
      set(PACKAGE_NAME ${ARG_LIB_NAME})
   endif()


   include(FetchContent)
   FetchContent_Declare(${ARG_LIB_NAME}
      GIT_REPOSITORY    "${ARG_GIT_REPOSITORY}"
      GIT_TAG           "${ARG_GIT_TAG}"
   )

   FetchContent_GetProperties(${ARG_LIB_NAME}
      POPULATED LIB_POPULATED
   )

   message(STATUS "Checking if ${ARG_LIB_NAME} is populated: ${LIB_POPULATED}")
   if (NOT LIB_POPULATED})      
      message(STATUS "Populating ${ARG_LIB_NAME}...")

      FetchContent_Populate(${ARG_LIB_NAME})

      set(LIB_BINARY_DIR ${${ARG_LIB_NAME}_BINARY_DIR})
      set(LIB_SOURCE_DIR ${${ARG_LIB_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR})

     message(STATUS "Configuring ${ARG_LIB_NAME}...")
     execute_process(
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        "-S ${LIB_SOURCE_DIR}"
        "-B ${LIB_BINARY_DIR}"
        "-DCMAKE_GENERATOR=${CMAKE_GENERATOR}"
        "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}"
        ${ARG_CONFIG_ARGS}
      WORKING_DIRECTORY "${LIB_BINARY_DIR}"
      COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT
      RESULT_VARIABLE result_config
     )
     if(result_config)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to config ${ARG_LIB_NAME} exited with result: ${result_config}")
     else()
      message(STATUS "${ARG_LIB_NAME} configuring complete!")
     endif()
     
     foreach(config_type IN LISTS ARG_CONFIG_TYPES)
        set(${ARG_LIB_NAME}_CONFIG_TYPE "${config_type}" CACHE INTERNAL "Config/build type for ${ARG_LIB_NAME}")
        message(STATUS "Building  ${ARG_LIB_NAME}... with CONFIG: ${config_type}")
        execute_process(
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
            --build "${LIB_BINARY_DIR}"
            --config "${config_type}"
            WORKING_DIRECTORY "${LIB_BINARY_DIR}"
            COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT
            ${ARG_BUILD_ARGS}
            RESULT_VARIABLE   result_build
            )
     endforeach()
     
     if(result_build)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to build ${ARG_LIB_NAME} with result: ${result_build}")
     else()
      message(STATUS "${ARG_LIB_NAME} build complete!")
     endif()
   endif()
   if (DEFINED ARG_COMPONENTS)
      find_package(${PACKAGE_NAME} REQUIRED
         COMPONENTS ${ARG_COMPONENTS}
         PATHS ${LIB_BINARY_DIR}
         NO_DEFAULT_PATH
      )
   else()
      find_package(${PACKAGE_NAME} REQUIRED
         PATHS ${LIB_BINARY_DIR}
         NO_DEFAULT_PATH
      )
   endif()
endfunction()
```

What it does is as follows:

1. Downloads from git a repository with a specific tag
2. Configures the build system of the downloaded library
3. Builds the library as part of the main project configure stage
4. Makes sure that FindPackage can discover the newly built library

Then, in my CMakeLists.txt for my project, I use it like so:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)

fetch_and_build_lib(
  LIB_NAME "mylib"
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/myRepo/myLib.git"
  GIT_TAG "1.2.3"
  CONFIG_ARGS "-DMYLIB_DOC=OFF;-DMYLIB_TEST=OFF"
  CONFIG_TYPES "debug, release"
  PACKAGE_NAME "MyLIB"
)

find_package(MyLIB REQUIRED)

#Use Release version of library for Debug, MinSizeRel, RelWithDebInfo build types:
set_target_properties(MyLIB PROPERTIES
  MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_MINSIZEREL Release
  MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELWITHDEBINFO Release
  MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_DEBUG Release
  )
target_link_libraries(main myLib::myLib)
```

This invokes the previously defined function that downloads, configures and builds the library. It assumes that the library correctly exports its targets, and then remaps the imported configs to the current project config.
This is what actually ends up linking the debug lib with the release executable.

[CMake documentation for MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html)

***Mandatory disclaimer:***

*Mixing release libs and debug executables is filled with pitfalls, both for shared and static libraries. I'm not discussing whether this is a good idea or not, or what the pitfalls are. Be sure you are aware of the limitations and what is safe and what is not safe to do when doing such a mix.*